# SQLITE get next row after ORDERBY

Tags: sqlite

I need to get the next row from an ORDERBY query

I have 2 columns, ID(Primary key), Age(float) in a table T and I need something like the following

```
SELECT ID FROM T WHERE !> (inputted ID) + 1 rowID/Next row <! ORDERBY Age (then primary key, but I suspect if the Age values are the same SQLite would default to order by primary key anyway) LIMIT 1
```

Essentially it would select the next row after the inputted ID in the ordered table, its the *next row / rowID + 1* I am not sure how to get.

As suggested here is a data set as an example

https://dbfiddle.uk?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=19685ac20cc42041a59d318a01a2010f

```
ID  Age
1   12.2
2   36.8
3   22.5
4   41
5   16.7
```

I am attempting to get the the following row from the ordered (by age) list given a specific ID

```
ID  Age
1   12.2
5   16.7
3   22.5
2   36.8
4   41
```

Something similar to

```
SELECT ID FROM OrderedInfo WHERE ID = 5 ORDER BY Age ASC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1;
```

My expected result would be '3' from the example data above

I have expanded the data set to include duplicate entries as I didn't implicitly state it could have such data - as such forpas answer works for the first example with no duplicate entries - thanks for your help
https://dbfiddle.uk?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=f13d7f5a44ba414784547d9bbdf4997e

Comment: Post sample data and expected results, better in a fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27 to clarify what you want.

Comment: Added an example as you suggested - sorry it took long to respond

Answer (score 1):

Use a subquery for the ID that you want in the WHERE clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM OrderedInfo
WHERE Age > (SELECT Age FROM OrderedInfo WHERE ID = 5)
ORDER BY Age LIMIT 1;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=0bb54d43bdbba6e4777c40a031733563).

If there are duplicate values in the column `Age` use a CTE that returns the row that you want and join it to the table so that you expand the conditions:

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT ID, Age FROM OrderedInfo WHERE ID = 5)
SELECT o.*
FROM OrderedInfo o INNER JOIN cte c
ON o.Age > c.Age OR (o.Age = c.Age AND o.ID > c.ID)  
ORDER BY o.Age, o.ID LIMIT 1;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=fbc5427b8c62b1ade13b6c1a38fd5fc4).

Comment: This looks promising - my only question to ask with this is will the ordered results always be the same order - e.g. if there are multiple entries with the same age, will they always be ordered the same every time the query is made? or would I need to add another ORDER BY in the sub query to ensure they always show the same?

Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @SJones if the order of the rows is not  uniquely defined by the expressions you use in the ORDER BY clause there is no guarantee that you will always get the same results.

Comment: Awesome, thanks, that's exactly what I needed

Comment: I have been experimenting with your answer, unfortunately I come across the original problem that I cant select the next line if for example I have 2 or more with the same age.
```
SELECT *
FROM OrderedInfo
WHERE  Age >= (SELECT Age FROM OrderedInfo WHERE ID = 6)
AND ID != 6 
ORDER BY Age, ID LIMIT 1;
```
I have expanded the data set example with multiple entries with the same age - as it is getting a greater age than the current age it will skip any that has the same age - using the >= doesn't then make the query work

Comment: @SJones this is something that you must clarify with sample data and expected results. Your current sample data imply that there are no duplicate ages and my code solves that requirement only.

Comment: Sorry about that, it was just a quick example, while in real world there shouldn't be any duplications - there is always that 1 in a million that it could :S
https://dbfiddle.uk?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=f13d7f5a44ba414784547d9bbdf4997e

Comment: @SJones see my edited answer.